# Elasticsearch Delete by query using jest

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I find an interesting feature called [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-usage.html).
How do I use it with [jest client](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`DeleteByQuery` class](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/eb2d90d0504a6e3db874cc8bd14efe4913451173/jest-common/src/main/java/io/searchbox/core/DeleteByQuery.java) like shown below:

```
    DeleteByQuery deleteAllUserJohn = new DeleteByQuery.Builder("{\"user\":\"john\"}")
            .addIndex("users")
            .addType("user")
            .build();
    client.execute(deleteAllUserJohn);
```

Also note that if you're running ES 2.x or above, the [Delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin) needs to be installed from a plugin first.

```
./bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```