# Delete ElasticSearch by Query with JEST

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have some custom data(let's call **Camera**) in my ElasticSearch, the data showed in Kibana is like

[image]

And I tried to delete data by Query according to the accepted answer in this article [ElasticSearch Delete by Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760557/elasticsearch-delete-by-query-using-jest), my code is like

```
String query = "{\"Name\":\"test Added into Es\"}";
DeleteByQuery delete = new DeleteByQuery.Builder(query).addIndex(this._IndexName).addType(this._TypeName).build();

JestResult deleteResult = this._JestClient.execute(delete);
```

And the result is **404 Not Found**.

Its obvious that there exist **one** Camera data in ElasticSearch which **Name** match the query, so I believe the **404** is caused by other reason.

Did I do anything wrong? Should I change the query string?

Answer (score 1):

The query needs to be a real query, not a partial document

Try with this instead

```
String query = "{\"query\": { \"match\": {\"Name\":\"test Added into Es\"}}}";
```

Comment: Can you share the full error please? and also which version of ES you're using

Comment: Sure! The full content is this `{"found":false,"_index":"cameras","_type":"camera","_id":"_query","_version":1,"result":"not_found","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}`. And I'm using ElasticSearch 5.4.0.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. Jest uses the `_query` endpoint which was the endpoint used by the Delete by query plugin back in ES 2.x. From ES 5 onwards, the delete by query feature has made it into the core and the endpoint is now named `_delete_by_query`. That [change has been made recently](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/issues/434) in Jest and will soon be released

Comment: So you have a few options: 1) downgrade to ES 2.4, 2) wait until the new Jest gets released or 3) checkout the Jest master branch and build it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for responding so lately... I didn't search afterwards, because building it by myself is quite impossible for me to achieve, and also I transfer my work on another part, so I didn't work on this issue anymore. But still very appreciate for your information and suggestions, hope there would be a way to solve(hopefully provided by JEST) afterwards. Thanks!