# delete by query in jest elastic search 5.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am looking to delete a document by query using jest client. In elastic search 2.0 it can be done by adding `delete by query` plugin and by writing the code

```
DeleteByQuery deleteAllUserJohn = new DeleteByQuery.Builder("{\"user               \":\"john\"}")
        .addIndex("users")
        .addType("user")
        .build();
client.execute(deleteAllUserJohn);
```

But this is not supporting in elastic 5.5. There should be solution for this but I am not getting it after lots of searching. Please suggest how to do this or if there any link for that please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Search document id first and then delete those ids.

Comment: ya..Actually I have two scenarios. One is delete by document id and another is delete by user Id which is indexed. Delete by document id is working for me.

Comment: Which version of Jest are you using?

Comment: And this answer might help, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324251/4604579

Comment: @Val That means it has yet to be release by jest client and need to checkout the Jest master branch and build it myself. right?

Comment: @val I am using 5.3.2